# How to get mysqli update to remove substring x amount of times?

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok, in my database I have two columns, mastered and collecting. Both of them should hold just a string. In collecting I have newdeck01, newdeck02, newdeck03... etc all the way up to newdeck15.

What I want to happen is that all the "newdeck"'s be removed from collecting and "newdeck-(date here)" added to mastered. The mastered part is working perfectly, but when I run the code, even though it TELLS me:

newdeck01, was removed from collecting

newdeck02, was removed from collecting

newdeck03, was removed from collecting

etc...
ONLY newdeck15 is removed. I don't understand why it would echo each one, but not actually run the query each time. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!!

```
$select=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]'");
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) { 
    $collecting=$row2['collecting'];
    $mast=$row2['mastered'];
    $id=$row2['id'];

    $newmastered=$master."-".$date.", ";
    $mastered=$mast.$master.$newmastered;

    for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
        if($i<10) {
            $in="0".$i;
        }
        else {
            $in=$i;
        }
        $remove=$master.$in.", ";
        $newcollect=str_replace($remove,"",$collecting);
        $update = "UPDATE `members` SET collecting='$newcollect' WHERE id='$id'";
        if (mysqli_query($connect, $update)) { 
            echo $remove."was removed from collecting<br>";  
        }
    }
    $update1 = "UPDATE `members` SET mastered='$mastered' WHERE id='$id'";
    if (mysqli_query($connect, $update1)) {   
        echo $newmastered." was added to the database.<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Normalize your table structure, don't put comma-delimited lists in a column.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $update` to see what it's actually doing?

Comment: I suspect the actual problem is that `str_replace()` isn't finding anything to replace.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but it doesn't help - that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out. When I `echo $update'` I find "newdeck01, newdeck02..." etc - everything except for newdeck15.

Comment: There's no `,` after `newdeck15`, since it's the last one in the list, but `$remove` always ends with `,`

Comment: Sorry, I just typed that incorrectly. There really is a comma after newdecks15 in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each time through the `for()` loop, you're doing the `str_replace()` on the original value of `$collecting`. So even though you're removing one of the `newdeckXX` items from it, you're putting that one back the next time. You need to set `$collecting` to `$newcollect` each time, to remove all of them.

Or better yet, make all the changes to `$collecting` in the loop, and then do a single `UPDATE`.

```
for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
    $remove = sprintf('%s%02d, ', $master, $i);
    $collecting = str_replace($remove, '', $collecting);
}
$update = "UPDATE `members` SET collecting='$collecting' WHERE id='$id'";
if (mysqli_query($connect, $update)) { 
    echo $remove."was removed from collecting<br>";  
}
```

Note that `if (mysqli_query(...))` only tells you if the query got an error, not whether it actually updated anything. If you want to know if anything was updated, use `mysqli_affected_rows($connect)` to get the number of rows that were updated.

Comment: While I don't really understand `sprintf` or `preg_replace` personally, this totally worked! (I added the commas back in, because even newdeck15, does have a comma, I just misspoke earlier.) Thank you!!

Comment: I went back to `str_replace()` after that comment.

Comment: I used `sprintf()` as a simpler way to put the leading 0 onto the numbers.